# nodejs mysql verify if value exists

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

i want to know if it's possible to verify a request in nodejs after made a request in a database.

this is my code:

```
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM * WHERE  * = ${pEvent.xxxxx};`, async (e, resultat) => {
      if(e){
        throw e
      }
      if(!resultat[0].xxxxx){
        console.log(`The item target of ${pEvent.xxxx} called ${pEvent.xxxx} doesn't exist... Do you want to create it ?`)
      }else{
        const tItemId = resultat[0].xxxx
      }
```

Even after this "if" the logs say that it's impossible to read property 'xxxxxxx' of undefined

there's the log:
[image: logs]

Comment: As the log says, `resultat[0]` is `undefined`. Can't access a property from undefined right.

Comment: Yeah this is what i've saw after posting this question. I'm sorry and thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entry doesn't exists, then the `resultat` will be an empty array, try this instead:

```
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM * WHERE  * = ${pEvent.xxxxx};`, async (e, resultat) => {
  if(e){
    throw e
  }
  if(!resultat || resultat.length < 1 || !resultat[0].xxxxx){
    console.log(`The item target of ${pEvent.xxxx} called ${pEvent.xxxx} doesn't exist... Do you want to create it ?`)
  }else{
    const tItemId = resultat[0].xxxx
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you !
This is what i've done after ask this question:

```
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM * WHERE  * = ${pEvent.xxxxx};`, async (e, resultat) => {
      if(e){
        throw e
      }
      if(resultat[0] === undefined){
        console.log(`The item target of ${pEvent.xxxx} called ${pEvent.xxxx} doesn't exist... Do you want to create it ?`)
      }else{
        const tItemId = resultat[0].xxxx
      }
```

and it's working, i'm gonna use your solution because there is more verification so less chance to have any crash :)